# How to add custom Module in requirements

Tags: python, azure-functions

I am currently working with Azure function.

When I attempt to run and debug, I encounter an error;

```
No module named {My custom module Name}. 
Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module.
```

and the error code points to my import module.

May I know how to resolve this issue or how should I add my custom Module to the requirements? 
Does it mean I cannot use module for Azure functions?

I am trying to run and debug visual Studio code on a time trigger function from Azure.
I was expecting that the code would be able to use modules I created in different `.py files`. Apparently it triggers errors.

My Code Structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Qm3.png)
in a local python

```
import datetime
import logging
import import2SQL_Life as ISQL
import GetFromAPI as GA
import azure.functions as func


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    company=GA.GetRefrenceCompanies() 
    ISQL.insertCompaniesSQL(company)
    print("done")
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

Comment: Can you provide your code in the question?

Comment: And your files architecture.

Comment: Is your custom module in a local python file or is it hosted somewhere, such as Github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No module named {My custom module Name}
> .  Please check the requirements.txt
> file for the missing module.

You are getting the above error because of the below project structure,

[image]

**Output**:

You should change the project structure as below, then only you will get the output,

[image]